# Python re.match recursive call memory leak

Tags: python, regex, memory-leaks

My function is in the following way to handle file line by line.
There are multiple error patterns defined and need to apply to each line.
I use multiprocessing.Pool to handle the file in block.

The memory usage increases to 2G for a 1G file.
And stays in 2G even after the file processing.
File closed in the end.

If I comment out the call to re_pat.match, memory usage is normal and keeps under 100Mb.

am I using re in a wrong way?
I cannot figure out a way to fix the memory leak.

```
def line_match(lines, errors)
    for error in errors:
        try:
            re_pat = re.compile(error['pattern'])
        except Exception:
            print_error
            continue

        for line in lines:
            m = re_pat.match(line)
            # other code to handle matched object 



def process_large_file(fo):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    while True:
        lines = list(itertools.islice(fo, line_per_proc))
        if not lines:
            break
        result = p.apply_async(line_match, args=(errors, lines))
```

Notes:
I omit some code as I think the significant difference is with/without re_pat.match(...)

Comment: What exactly is your code doing? It isn't clear.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I update the code indent. It is applying a list of error patterns to each line of the file to find matched object.

Comment: Quick question. What is `lines`? Where does it come from?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ updated. Thanks. it's a list.